# Concurrent consumers of Seda in Apache camel

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, apache-camel

I have a route as mentioned below. The route polls a directory at regular interval and reads a big size .csv file. It then split the files in chunk of 1000 lines and sends it to the seda `queue(firstQueue)`. I have 15 concurrent consumers on this seda queue.

```
route.split().tokenize("\n", 1000).streaming().to("seda:firstQueue?concurrentConsumers=15").process(myProcessor).to("seda:secondQueue?concurrentConsumers=15").process(anotherMyProcessor);
```

1) What does 15 concurrent consumers means - does it means 15 threads read data from the seda and pass it to one instance of `myProcessor`? Or 15 separate instance of `myProcessor` are created each one acting on the same copy of the data? Note that `myProcessor` is a singleton, what will happen if I change it to prototype.

2) Is it possible that any two or more threads pick the same data and pass it to the `myProcessor`? Or is it guaranteed that no two threads will have the same data ?

Appreciate a quick response. Thanks!

Comment: I am using quite an old version of camel - 2.10.1. Is anyone aware if there were issues with seda and concurrentConsumers in this version and might have been fixed in later version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863298/how-apache-camel-seda-component-works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Camel is a bit rusty but I'm pretty sure that

1. There are 15 threads running. Each will read a message from the queue and call myProcessor. There is only one instance of my processor so you need to make sure that it is thread safe. I've never tried the it, but I don't believe changing the scope to prototype will make any difference.
2. Two threads should not pick up the same message from the queue. In normal running each message should get processed just once. However, there are error conditions that my result in the same message being processes twice, the most obvious one being that you restart the app part way through processing the file.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the reply. So, since SEDA is basically a "BlockingQueue", is it ensured that no two threads will have the same copy of the message? Also, once a thread picks up a message from the queue, that message is removed immediately from the queue then ?

Comment: Yes, a blocking queue is exactly what it is. Once a thread picks up a message, it is immediately removed from the queue so no other thread is going to pick up the same message.

Comment: One more question, even though I have 15 concurrentConsumer defined, I see only 1 thread processing (by myProcessor) the messages. Any idea why this is happenning ?

Comment: No idea off the top of my head I'm afraid.